# can i get adsense on another website?

Tags: show, adsense, sites

I have two different websites, let's call them site 1 and site 2. Site 1 is the site I used to get my adsense approval and I can show ads on this site.

However, I'd like to show ads on my 2nd site as well but somehow I can't. I created an ad block and placed the code on my 2nd site but the add never shows and goes to idle after a while.

Do I need to register this website URL at the adsense management page or something?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can places ads on more than one website. Check the following:

- Does the second site has any visitors? If not, the ad will go idle.
- If the ad does show up at least once, you know you did the right thing. But refreshing your page too often will cause the ads to stop showing. Because you request ads from the same IP, adsense stops displaying ads after a couple of times. After a certain unknown timeframe, ads will show up from your IP again.
- Do you use the correct code? (as in: the code from the new created ad)